# libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work

Tags: python, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I'm on python; I am trying to shut down a function running through a ThreadPoolExecutor, but the shutdown is crashing with the error:

```
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
```

The function is submitted with:

```
record_future = self.executor.submit(next,primitive)
```

`primitive` is an iterator that usually returns a value but in some cases, it needs to wait a while before returning a value (because of long calculations, etc). In these cases, when I need to shut down the running thread, I cannot wait for the iterator to finish returning, and need to shut it down immediately. I did it with:

```
executor.shutdown(wait=False)
```

However, when execution reaches this point, I get the libgcc error.

I tried 'solving' it by manually installing with:

```
apt-get install libgcc1:amd64
```

but no dice. I am not sure where exactly python is looking for this library, otherwise I would try creating a symbolic link, because the library is already installed at:

```
$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libgcc
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x32) => /usr/libx32/libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a potential workaround in the [Python mailing list](https://bugs.ams1.psf.io/issue18748#msg339502) to explicitly load `libgcc_.so.1` via `ctypes` as follows:

```
import ctypes
libgcc_s = ctypes.CDLL('libgcc_s.so.1')
```

One has to make sure that this is loaded before any threads are created and that the variable `libgcc_s` lasts until all of the threads are closed (i.e. put this at the beginning of your file).

Comment: I tried this method, but I now get the following:

`
OSError: /mnt/d/Projects/EBKA/edna_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/vendor/libssl.so.1.1: symbol EVP_idea_cbc version OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference
`

Comment: I have libgcc_s.so.1 issue with python multi-threading. First, I experience OSError just like @asuprem using this solution. Then, put the solution at the top of my code before any import solve it

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Python 3.7 or 3.8?

I also encounter this error in Python's `sounddevice` using my Anaconda Python 3.8, but it does not happen using my Anaconda Python 3.7. I have tested all workarounds in Google search, and have made sure all related packages and libraries are of the same version, it still does not work. My last conjecture is Python 3.8 vs 3.7 version difference. Though it might not be the case ^_^

Comment: I have the same error using tqdm package with Python 3.8.0. And also it does not happen with Python 3.6.9. I don't have any ideas but I found https://bugs.ams1.psf.io/issue42888

Comment: I have double-checked, I am pretty sure that libgcc_s.so.1 is installed and accessible. It seems to be the delay-load-dynamic-library feature of Python 3.8 that is causing it to occur in multiple packages.

Comment: This worked for me with a deepspeed issue building cpu_adam. Just downgrade python from 3.8 to 3.78. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I found a solutions for ubuntu user in this blog https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn/issues/604, in summary try before running the script

`export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`.